# Google Tag Manager regex works differently from regex101

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I want to get the first value of URL after the domain. So I used regex.
See demo here:
https://regex101.com/r/nDzJlb/1

[Tag Manager Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO3Ze.png)

However it doesn't really appears to be working the same way. Any help would be appreciated
[GA4 Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkAP7.png)

I tried writing regex

Comment: I don't know anything about Google tag manager, but you selected the PHP Regex flavor in Regex101. Are you sure Google uses the PHP flavor and not the ECMA or .NET flavor of Regex? Also in Regex101 you're using Regex options `gm`. Are you sure you're using the same Regex options in Google tag manager?

Comment: Except Rust, all other return the same result.

Comment: This won't solve your issue, but `http[s]:` is exactly the same as `https:`. Perhaps you meant `https?:` (to make the `s` optional)

Comment: Yeah, the s is optional, but it really doesn't matter in that case.

Comment: @maraaaaaaaa and IAP: Google Tag Manager regex uses RE2 flavor (also used by Go), which, as far as I know, is irrelevant in this particular situation.

Comment: To replicate the problem, we need the actual input content *as text*. Please [don't post images of code/error/textual content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: In the mean time, I would say that you can optimize your regex by making it more specific: [`https?://[^/]+/([^/?#]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/nDzJlb/2).

Comment: @InSync the code is available in the regex101 link. It is impossible to add code in Stack Overflow it asks me to do things I don't understand.

Comment: If SO is complaining about your post not containing code, check if you have wrapped your code in triple backticks.